# How to add value comma-separated parameter calling SQL query using SQLCMD via Powershell

Tags: sql, variables, powershell-2.0, sqlcmd

I'm writing a PowerShell script that makes a call with SQLCMD to execute a .sql file and output a CSV file.  In SQLCMD command, I want to pass a parameter back to query that includes a value of comma-separated list so I can use in an 'IN' statement.

```
select a, b, c, d
from dbtbl (nolock)
where client_id in ($(clients))
```

The SQLCMD command works if I assign $client_id to a singular value i.e. '000_abc' but does not work if I assign the variable as an array. i.e. '000_abc','000_def', '000_ghi'

```
# Input variables
  $SQLSourceFolder = "V:\PS\queries\"
  $FolderFile = "V:\PS\Myoutput.csv"
  $TaxCode = "MY*script*.sql"
  $qtr = "'1'"
  $year = "'2019'"

  #Works Fine.  Only one client filtered in SQL query where clause
  $client_id = "'000_abc'"

  #Doesn't Work. Multiple clients filtered in SQL query where clause with IN statement.
  # $client_id = "'000_abc','000_def', '000_ghi'"

# Find all files matching $TaxCode filter in the folder specified
  Get-ChildItem -Path $SQLSourceFolder -Filter $TaxCode | ForEach-Object {

    cls

    Start-Process "D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\SQLCMD.EXE" -ArgumentList @("-S","tcp:XXXXXXXXXXXXXX,1433", "-d" ,"XXX", "-U", "XXXXXXXX", "-P" ,"XXXXXXXXXX", " -v", " qtr = $qtr", " yr = $year", " clients = $client_id", " -W ", "-s", "~", "-i",  "$($_.FullName)", "-o", "$FolderFile")
}
```

The expected result would be to pass multi-value variable to sql query where parameter is used in where clause with IN statement.

Comment: Any thoughts on this issue?

Comment: we're all giving our time freely here, and many of us know what it's like to post a question and get no answers.

I'll try to help, but please bear in mind that your question holds zero technical interest. (No offense intended.) If you ask about React, F#, or service meshes, you'll get more interest. This question is the equivalent of asking strangers to mow your lawn.

Answer (score 0):

How come you're using `sqlcmd.exe` instead of `Invoke-SqlCmd` or, better yet, `Invoke-SqlCmd2`?

> Quick context: `Invoke-SqlCmd2` is a community drop-in replacement for `Invoke-SqlCmd` which addresses a few issues. It's widely considered the best solution for querying MS SQL from PS. Relevant: `Install-Module Invoke-SqlCmd2`, https://github.com/sqlcollaborative/Invoke-SqlCmd2

As you are discovering, passing arguments in to native applications is surprisingly difficult. It's always better to use PS commands where possible, in my experience.

Let me know if there's a good reason not to use `Invoke-SqlCmd2` and I'll see what I can do to mock this for you, but it's a non-trivial effort on my part, so I do encourage you to just follow normal practice!